# Can't access options for ng-options inside an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options

I would like to be able to access a set of select options within an ng-options inside an ng-repeat, but the ng-repeat creates a new scope where I can no longer access this. Is there a way around this without adding it to the repeating data?

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="container">
    <test repeater="repeater"></test>
</body>
```

Template:

```
<div ng-repeat="repeat in repeater">
    <span>{{repeat.type}}</span>
    <select ng-options="value for value in options">
         <option value="">Choose one:</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.repeater = [
    {
      type: 'best'
    },
    {
      type: 'worst'
    },
    {
      type: 'ok'
    }
  ];
});

angular.module('app').directive('test', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      repeater: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.options = ['Nope', 'Yup', 'Sure'];
    }
  };
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gjmatLbgYvK5xp0ZyOGq?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but missing 1 thing. `ng-model`

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="value for value in options">
     <option value="">Choose one:</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Right, `ng-model` is required with `ng-options`. However, you don't need `label as`.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I don't know why I thought that was necessary.